# Change attribute from text to dropdown

Tags: magento2, database, product-attribute, select

How can I convert a product attribute type from Text to Dropdown in Magento?

I already have attribute values assigned to many products, so don't want to lose these in the process.

Comment: Use `Select` type

Comment: How and where do I choose "Select" type?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: No. It's not that easy. As the option is greyed out. Changing it also implies a lot of database changes. So I've yet to find the solution...

Answer (score 3):

Magento Won't allow you to change input type of an attribute, and if you somehow change it from database, values of attributes would still not work for you, as **Text** stores just a value whereas **dropdown** stores id of each option's **value**

Instead of working on changing attribute type you can do this:

- You need to export the data from magento exporter. Like, **sku**, **your_attribute**
- Delete existing attribute
- Create new one with the same attribute code **your_attribute**
- Import the data that you have just exported

Comment: Doesn't this interfere with native magento functions such as ->setColor(

Answer (score 0):

You can done this programmatically...

For Magento 2.4.3 Complete code is given below...

Design (TextField) => Wzor(Dropdown)

Department(TextField) => Motyw(Dropdown)

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$action = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productcollection */

$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('id');
// Convert these attributes from Text Field to Dropdown
$convertAttributes = [
    'design' => 'wzor',
    'department' => 'motyw',
];
echo "Found " . $productcollection->getSize() . " total products" . PHP_EOL;
foreach($productcollection as $_product)
{
    
    $productId = $_product->getId();
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    $updateAttributes = array();
    
    foreach ($convertAttributes as $from => $to) {
        // Get current text value from product
        $wzor = trim($product->getData($from));
        if ($wzor != "") {
            // Get new attribute
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $_attr */
            $_attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($to);
            if ($_attr->usesSource()) {
                // Find existing Option for this product's value
                $wzor_id = $_attr->getSource()->getOptionId($wzor);
                // if not found, get or create new Option
                if (!$wzor_id) {
                    getOrSetAttribute($objectManager, $to, $wzor);
                    $_attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($to);
                    $_attr->usesSource();
                    // Get new option ID
                    $wzor_id = $_attr->getSource()->getOptionId($wzor);
                }
                echo "Updated attribute " . $_attr->getId() . " `" . $_attr->getAttributeCode() . "` for Product " . $productId . " `" . $product->getSku() . "`" . PHP_EOL;
                $updateAttributes[$to] = $wzor_id;
            }
        }
    }
     
    if(!empty($updateAttributes)){
        try{
            $action->updateAttributes([$productId], $updateAttributes, 0);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Unable to update product " . $productId . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }
    }       
    echo "Product ".$productId." Design Pattern updated";
}

function getOrSetAttribute($objectManager, $attibutecode, $values){
    $eavAttributeFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory');
    $attributeOptionManagement = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface');
    
    $magentoAttribute = $eavAttributeFactory->create()->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attibutecode);   
    $attributeCode = $magentoAttribute->getAttributeCode();
    $magentoAttributeOptions = $attributeOptionManagement->getItems(
        'catalog_product',
        $attributeCode
    );
    $attributeOptions = array($values);
    $existingMagentoAttributeOptions = array();
    $newOptions = array();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($magentoAttributeOptions as $option) {
        if (!$option->getValue()) {
            continue;
        }
        if($option->getLabel() instanceof \Magento\Framework\Phrase) {
            $label = $option->getText();
        } else {
            $label = $option->getLabel();
        }
    
        if($label == '') {
            continue;
        }
    
        $existingMagentoAttributeOptions[] = $label;
        $newOptions['value'][$option->getValue()] = array($label, $label);
        $counter++;
    }
    
    foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
        if($option == '') {
            continue;
        }
    
        if(!in_array($option, $existingMagentoAttributeOptions)) {
            $newOptions['value']['option_'.$counter] = array($option, $option);
        }
    
        $counter++;
    }
    
    if(count($newOptions)) {
        $magentoAttribute->setOption($newOptions)->save();
    }
    
}
```