# covert Text field to drop down selection

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, drop-downs, selection

HI I downloaded an extension (checkout-custom-form) from here, I want to modify his extension,
https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form
the extension itself work wonderful.

having below XML code and it will display as a text box, how do I convert into dropdown selection box?

restaurant, government, education, retailer ...etc

```
  <item name="checkout_industry" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
     <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
     <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/textarea</item>
     <item name="cols" xsi:type="string">15</item>
     <item name="rows" xsi:type="string">2</item>
  </item>
      <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
      <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_industry</item>
      <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Industry</item>
      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
</item>
```

[image]

custom_field.phtml

```
    <?php
/** @var Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Block\Order\CustomFields $block */

/** @var Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Model\Data\CustomFields $customFields */
$customFields = $block->getCustomFields($block->getOrder());
?>
<?php if($customFields): ?>
    <div class="block block-order-details-view">
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="box">
                <strong class="box-title"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Other information') ?></span></strong>
                <div class="box-content">
               
            </div>

            <div class="box">
                <strong class="box-title"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Industry') ?></span></strong>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($customFields->getCheckoutIndustry())); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260309/85907

Comment: check --- https://toweringmedia.com/blog/magento-2-change-text-attribute-dropdown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get this solve by reference this site
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-new-input-form-magento-2.html

```
   <item name="checkout_industry" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
       <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
       <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
   </item>
       <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Please select value</item>
               <item name="value" xsi:type="string"></item>
           </item>
           <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 1</item>
               <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_1</item>
           </item>
           <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Value 2</item>
               <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>
           </item>
       </item>
   <item name="value" xsi:type="string">value_2</item>                                                                                      
   <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
   <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_industry</item>
   <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Industry</item>
   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
```